# Access a class property by both class name and parent class name

Tags: python

Consider this snippet:

```
def populate(l):
    l.append(1)


class First:
    __obj__ = []


class Second(First):
    populate(First.__obj__)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self):
        for i in Second.__obj__:
            print(i)


a = Second()
a()
```

When run, it will output `1`, so it seems that `First.__obj___` and `Second.__obj__` point to the same object. Is it true and how does class property work in the case of inheritance?

Comment: By using append you are modifying `__obj__` in place. If you want different values of `__obj__` in `First` or `Second` namespace, I would advise using the constructor of `Second` to have `__obj__` pointing to a different object. What exactly are you trying to do or understand here?

Comment: Note that if you populate outside of the class you get the same result. You just are assigning a value to the First property. Then you derive a Second class that inherits the properties of First. Not sure this helps

Comment: @Learningisamess this is a simplified version, actually in `First` I have a classmethod that will print the content of `__obj__`, and in `Second` I will interact with `__obj__` right when defining the class (outside of any method, similar to the position of `populate`, thus it's impossible to call it with `Second.__obj__`), so I just want to confirm the behavior of class property in the case of inheritance, that they indeed point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The name `__obj__` is an attribute of the `First` class. Because the `Second` class inherits the `First` class, it also inherits the class attribute `__obj__`. Both `First.__obj__` and `Second.__obj__` are referencing the same `list` object. An instance's `self.__obj__` also references the same object.

This is because `list`s are mutable. This would not be the case with an immutable type like `str`.